# Downcast from 'CLLocation?' to 'CLLocation' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocation

I'm trying to display the users current location on a map view but I'm getting an error on the first line of the location manager function

Here is my code

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapkitView: MKMapView!
var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
    {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    let location = locations.last as! CLLocation

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    self.mapkitView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
}
```

The error I'm getting is "Downcast from 'CLLocation?' to 'CLLocation' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

on line let location = locations.last as! CLLocation

Comment: You don't need the `as! CLLocation` since the array contains `CLLocation` you could just say `locations.last!` but please don't. Use a conditional unwrap `if let location = locations.last {`. However, if you read the documentation for `MKMapView` you will find it can do all of this for you if you enable user tracking mode.

Comment: Thanks I'm not getting any errors now but when it runs, it just shows a map without my location, any idea why?

Comment: Did you get prompted to allow location access?  Are you testing on the simulator or a real device?  If the simulator, did you simulate a location from the menu?  If a real device, does it have a location fix?

Comment: ah that was it i had to simulate a location in Xcode, thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are force-casting an `Optional` `CLLocation`to `CLLocation`, that is why Swift suggests to simply force unwrap it:

```
let location = locations.last!
```

This version (and yours) will crash if `locations` is empty.

Thus I recommend to never force unwrap anything and use `guard`instead:

```
guard let location = locations.last else {
    return
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'm not getting any errors now but when it runs, it just shows a map without my location, any idea why?

Comment: That is another topic. Follow @Paulw11's advice (enable user tracking mode) and/or post another question for that.